# How I can get the filename when I click on it using Win API?

Tags: c, winapi

How I can get the filename when I click on it using Win API ?

I need to get the text from any mouse clicked object on the screen using Win API,
I was able to get the text inside GUI Application (ex:button) using ***WindowFromPoint***, but I need to know the filename when I click on a file on the Desktop, or Explorer.

Comment: You need to be clear about what you are clicking on. A filename is a non-visual thing. You don't click on a file name. You click on a GUI object. Like a button or a list item. And you need to be much more clear about the technologies you use, and your goals. Do remember that all we know is presented in your question. We have no context beyond that.

Comment: After edit, it's now clear that the question is about a file in a explorer window. Maybe this could help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround is clicking twice (not double click), emulating Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C events and getting text from clipboard. Another way is using UI Automation API based framework (like [Teststack.White in C#](http://teststack.net/White/)) or calling UIA API immediately (see [AutomationElement.FromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.frompoint(v=vs.110).aspx)).